# Vue. How to bind data dynamically on event to table

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a graph (I use [vue-echarts](https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts) library) and I listen to the `dataZoom` event that is used to slice the initial graph.

On this event I call a method that calculates the metrics of the selected data. Then I want to pass theese metrics to the table.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <chart
          :options="candlestick"
          :init-options="initOptions"
          ref="candlestick"
          auto-resize
          @datazoom="actionOnDataZoom"
      />
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="metrics"
        hide-actions
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template slot="metrics" scope="props">
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.accumulativeReturn }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.annualReturn }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.annualVolatility }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.maxDrawdown }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.sharpeRatio }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.informationRatio }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </figure>
  </section>
</template>


<script>
import calculateMetrics from './metrics.js'
let periods = null

export default {
    name: "candlestick",
    props: {
      tsdata: {
        type: Array
      }
    },

data: function () {
  return {
    candlestick: getCandleStick(),
    rendered: false,
    initOptions: {
      renderer: 'canvas'
    },
    headers: [
      {text: 'Measure', value: 'name', sortable: false},
      {text: 'Accumulative Return', value: 'accumulativeReturn'},
      {text: 'Annual Return', value: 'annualReturn'},
      {text: 'Annual Volatility', value: 'annualVolatility'},
      {text: 'Max Drawdown', value: 'maxDrawdown'},
      {text: 'Sharpe Ratio', value: 'sharpeRatio'},
      {text: 'Information Ratio', value: 'informationRatio'},
    ],
     metrics: [{
      name: "2_",
      maxDrawdown: 10,
      accumulativeReturn: 0.055947072399999964,
      annualReturn: 0.05445355305534472,
      annualVolatility: 7.377778178783156,
      sharpeRatio: 0.007380752271997143,
      informationRatio: 0
    }],
    //Mock data
   }
},
  methods: {

      actionOnDataZoom: function(event, instance, echarts) {
        console.log(event.start, event.end)
        this.metrics = calculateMetrics(event.start, event.end)
  },
 }
</script>
```

The sample output of `calculateMetrics`

```
[{ accumulativeReturn: 100, 
annualReturn: 120, 
annualVolatility: 150, 
informationRatio: 180,
maxDrawdown: 100,
name: "string"
sharpeRatio: 20
}]
```

But I can't understand how can I pass the results to the table. My idea was to create a variable to store the result of `calculateMetrics(event.start, event.end)` function and bind it to the the table, but I'm not sure whether it is a good practice.

Comment: What's the return value of `calculateMetrics`? I think you can store in and pass to `v-data-table`

Comment: @ittus Hi I have updated my post. I tried pass the result of `calculateMetrics` but still the data is not shown

Comment: Is there any console error? Can you `console.log(this.metrics)` after `this.metrics = calculateMetrics(event.start, event.end)` and make sure you get some data?

Comment: Yes, I checked it

Comment: @ittus I tried to use mock data (see the editing), but it didn't help me either. There is no alert "No data available", but it doesn't render.

Comment: Oh, found the problem. slot should be equal to `items` not to `metrcis`